# What pathPrefix in Android to make entire domain a deep linking?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I want to set up deep linking so that any url of `myapp.io` is opened by the Android app if installed.

Is this a valid `pathPrefix`? Or should it be `"/*"`?

```
   "android": {
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.myapp.io",
              "pathPrefix": "*"
            }
          ],
          "category": [
            "BROWSABLE",
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },

The code above is from my app.json as I'm using Expo, but I think it's clear what React Native values they map to.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
"pathPattern": ".*"
```

From the docs:

```
 - pathPattern (string): a regex for paths that should be matched by the filter, e.g. ".*"
 - pathPrefix (string): a prefix for paths that should be matched by the filter, e.g. "/records/" will match "/records/123"
```

https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/